# Pass INT value from one Scene to another

Tags: ios, class, cocos2d-iphone, int

I am trying to pass a int value from a method I have in another file. I am building on cocos2d. I have the following code that calculates my int `energyInt`

```
-(void)energyCalculate{

    NSCalendar *c = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    //Get Current Date
    NSDate *d1 = [NSDate date];
    //Get Last Stamina Input
    NSDate *d2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"hunger_last_input"];
    NSDateComponents *components = [c components:NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:d2 toDate:d1 options:0];
    NSInteger diff = components.second;

    NSString * staminaString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"hunger"];
    NSInteger myInt = [staminaString intValue];

    energyInt = myInt - (diff * decreaseConstantChar);

    NSLog(@"ENERGY TEST STAMINA: %d", energyInt);

}
```

I am setting it up in the .h file

```
@interface staminaValues : CCNode

@property int energyInt;

-(void)energyCalculate;
```

**OTHER FILE**

Then in the other file I can call the value using the following which gives me the **correct value** through the `NSLOG`.

```
[_staminaValues energyCalculate];
```

However how do i then use/get the `energyInt` value?

I have tried the following however they return 0.

```
energy = _staminaValues.energyInt;
NSLog(@"Hunger Test : %d", energy);
NSLog(@"Hunger Test : %d", _staminaValues.energyInt);
NSLog(@"Hunger Test : %d", [_staminaValues energyInt]);
```

Comment: Does `_staminaValues == nil` by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the methods returntype to int

`-(int)energyCalculate();`

and add

`return energyInt`

to the end of the method.

Then you can access the int by

`int energy = [_staminaValues energyCalculate];`